# How to make listiterator back to back next() and previous() not return the same value?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, listiterator

This Test program returns the values in the comments `{ 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 }`, but I would like to change it so, that i receive `{ 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2 }`.
I found, that listIterator is like this because the cursor is in between the values like this:

`^1*2*3*4*`

The asterisk `*` is where the the cursor could be and the `^` is where it currently is. How to change it?

```
public class LinkedListIteratorTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            LinkedList<Integer> backForw = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            ListIterator<Integer> bFI;

            backForw.add(1);
            backForw.add(2);
            backForw.add(3);
            backForw.add(4);
            bFI = backForw.listIterator();

            System.out.println(bFI.next()); // 1
            System.out.println(bFI.next()); // 2
            System.out.println(bFI.previous()); // 2, how to make it return 1?
            System.out.println(bFI.next()); // 2, if the last one would be 1, this
                                            // should be 2.
            System.out.println(bFI.next()); // 3
            System.out.println(bFI.previous()); // 3, how to make it return 2?
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really think you're asking the wrong question here. Why not ask a question with how to get the behaviour you want rather than asking how to break the iterator?

Comment: Had the same problem. But in answer see correct explanation

Answer (score 2):

Using your notation, when you have the first call to BFI.next() the location of the cursor is:

> *1^2*3*4*

This returns one because the cursor passed over one while moving forward. After the next call to BFI.next() the location of the cursor is:

> *1*2^3*4*

As a result, when you call BFI.previous(), the cursor moves back by one, passing over and returning 2 and resulting in the following position:

> *1^2*3*4*

This is the correct behavior for a LinkedListIterator. Calling next() and then immediately calling previous() should always return the same value because you are iterating over the same element.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Conceptually, the definition of a Java iterator is that it points to the *spaces between the elements*.  When you move an iterator forwards or backwards it passes over an element and returns that element, coming to rest between the returned element and the next (or previous) element.

You could create a custom iterator, but any other behavior would lead to inconsistencies.  Before going down this path, ask yourself WHY you want an iterator to behave differently, and whether or not you can adjust your code to use the iterator as it is currently defined.